# password_compat for older php version

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

PHP 5.5 will [support](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) the password functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. Also there is a [file](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to add this functions in >5.3.7.

My problem is that I am currently running the debian package 5.3.3-7+squeeze14.

Is there a way to make this function available with this old PHP version?

Comment: Is there no way you can update your PHP? This would be the best solution.

Comment: It's not a one server problem. Many of my customers running not up to date PHP versions. At some of the servers I only have ftp/ssh or no access at all.

Comment: I see no other solution then rebuild those functions by hand coding.

Comment: @JvdBerg Hand-coding a pre 5.3.7 version of crypt() + bcrypt isn't really an option for most people

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, before I get started, let me make one thing clear. I am the author of the library in question (and the patch for 5.5).

With that said, what the others have mentioned is absolutely correct. The reason that 5.3.7 is the minimum version is that all versions prior have a bug in the bcrypt implementation that can lead to entropy loss in passwords using high-byte characters (code points >= 128).

That's the main reason for 5.3.7 being the minimum version. And I would **highly** suggest upgrading to at least 5.3.7, but preferably latest (a number of significant security issues have been found in not-so-old versions).

Now, what can you do if you're stuck on a lower version? You *could* fork the library and adjust `$2y$` to `$2a$`. That will at least get you to work. Passwords generated in this manner will be portable with future versions (the library is designed to be able to verify older `crypt()` passwords).

However, I would recommend that you do not do this. Just upgrade to a newer version of PHP. It's not that hard (there are deb packages from [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) that can do it for you).

If you really are stuck on an older version, I would suggest that you use a library that's designed for this. Something like my [PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib) or [PhPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (Note that you should only use that linked version of the library, there are several others on github that are drastically different).

Comment: +1. For people reading this in the future, please note that the 5.3.7 version requirement has been removed from the lib, since an up-to-date 5.3.3 from Debian (as per the question) includes the relevant patch. Instead, the installer for password_compat checks that the patch is in place by doing a test `crypt()` operation before proceeding.

Comment: I need to correct my previous comment. After trying to get password_compat working on a stock Debian Squeeze installation, it turns out that Debian Suqeeze does **not** support password_compat. Yes, Debian have back-ported the relevant security patches, but they *haven't* back-ported the `$2y$` hash option. I have php5.3.3-7-squeeze15: password_compat's `version_test` responds `false`, and code using the password functions also fails. @ircmaxell: this directly contradicts what I understood from reading the relevant tickets on github. Can you confirm this for me? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SDC: I did everything in that thread off of what everyone else was telling me about their testing. I'm going to download a Squeeze instance to load in a VM, and if it doesn't work, then I'm going to restore the version check.

Comment: Please comment here (or update the answer) once you have a confirmed answer one way or the other; I'm holding off switching to PasswordLib or PhPass until I know for sure. But re changing the code back... you know, I think I'd leave the version test as you have it -- it does the job it needs to, and even if Debian hasn't back-ported the fix, there may be other distros that have. Up to you, though.

Comment: @SDC: After booting up 6.0.7. it appears that Debian did **NOT** back-port that feature as others have described. I am going to re-implement that version check, as most people aren't running that `version-test.php` like they are supposed to... My advice: get off Debian...

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I guess I'll switch to your PasswordLib instead. Question: Is there any milage in trying to contact the Debian team and put the case for the feature to be back-ported. I guess they only back-port security fixes, but that's a fine line to draw with this particular issue. I for one can't get off Debian -- our ops team would fall on the floor laughing if I tried to suggest it, and I imagine it's the same story for a lot of other people; Debian is a pretty well-used distro, and well respected by sys admin folk.

Comment: @SDC: What about upgrading to a DOTDEB release of PHP. One that's actually maintained and somewhat recent...?

Comment: Its out of my hands. Our ops team are rigidly committed to sticking with the official supported Debian release. The guy in charge is Mr Picky; getting anything other than the offical Debian version is just not going to happen.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, point is sometimes the client website is hosted on a provider who doesn't have or want to update yet, in my case in one of my sites, i could not user your library since version was 5.3.24

Comment: @DannyG 5.3.24 > 5.3.7, so you can use it. But besides, it's up to you, the person who actually knows better, to push the client to get their host to update. You have that power. You're not stuck. It's on you to be the change you want to be...

Answer (score 5):

The reason that 5.3.7 was made the minimum version is due to fact that the `crypt()` function using bcrypt in earlier versions of PHP outputs wildly different results to current versions.

You can see the result for yourself: http://3v4l.org/3cAZf

Using the following code:

```
<?php
var_dump(crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2y$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$'));
```

#### Output for 5.3.7 - 5.3.16, 5.4.0 - 5.4.6

> string(60) "$2y$07$usesomesillystringfore2uDLvp1Ii2e./U9C8sBjqp8I90dH6hi"

#### Output for 4.3.0 - 4.3.11, 4.4.0 - 4.4.9, 5.0.0 - 5.0.5, 5.1.0 - 5.1.6, 5.2.0 - 5.2.17, 5.3.2 - 5.3.6

> string(13) "$25di0cl7EYZA"

#### Output for 5.3.0 - 5.3.1

> string(13) "$2v4FKr10WzJ2"

Answer (score 5):

PHP >= 5.3.7 is required because the fixed bcrypt algorithm `2y` was included in that version. The previous `2a` algorithm was broken for passwords with bytes outside the US-ASCII range.

There is a good chance that your 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 version also includes this fix. Distributions commonly stay at some specific version, but backport security fixes (like this one).

So you should just check if that algorithm is available and if it is you can safely use password_compat.

The [changelog](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze14/changelog) for the package is a bit unclear. It mentions that `2x` was added, but does not say whether `2y` was added too (but it probably was).

Comment: Thanks for the inside! Does this mean if I remove the version switch it should work? It looks like it does not. `password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` returns false because crypt returns a short hash.

Comment: @PiTheNumber What does `var_dump(crypt('foo', '$2y$05$bar'));` output for you?

Comment: @PiTheNumber And what does `var_dump(crypt("foo\xaabar", '$2a$05$bar'));` give you?